# Quero verificar se a string contem somente letras?

Tags: c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#define tam 50

main(){
    struct cadastro{
        char nome[tam];
    };
    struct cadastro dados;

    printf("Nome:");
    fgets(dados.nome,tam,stdin);
    fflush(stdin);

    if(isalpha(dados.nome[tam])){  //verificar se são letras
        printf("Nome: %s\n",strupr(dados.nome));  //converter para letra maiuscula
    }else{
        printf("Insira somente letras.\n");
    }

    system("pause > NULL");
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Não pode utilizar o `isalpha` como utilizou:

```
if(isalpha(dados.nome[tam])){
```

Assim está a utilizar apenas em um caratere o `50` que já está fora do intervalo valido no seu caso, que seria de `0` a `49`. Assim apenas sabe se esse caratere é uma letra.

Para fazer a validação que pretende tem de utilizar o [`isalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) em cada caratere, validando assim se todos são letras. Sugiro criar uma função só para essa verificação:

```
int apenas_letras(char *texto){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; texto[i] != '\0'; ++i){ //percorrer todos os carateres
        if (!isalpha(texto[i]) && texto[i] != ' '){ //se não for letra nem espaço
            return 0; //retornar 0 indicando que não tem somente letras
        }
    }
    return 1; //retornar 1 indica que só tem letras
}
```

Note que individualizei o espaço para que fosse também considerado como uma letra. Pode remover esse teste adicional se não for esse o seu objetivo.

Agora basta utilizar no `main` que já tem:

```
if(apenas_letras(dados.nome)){ //<--aqui
    printf("Nome: %s\n",strupr(dados.nome));  
}else{
    printf("Insira somente letras.\n");
}
```

Repare ainda que para funcionar corretamente tem que  tratar a `string` que é lida com o `fgets` pois este deixa o `\n` lido no fim, que irá interferir com a validação. Pode remove-lo da seguinte forma:

```
size_t tam_nome = strlen(dados.nome);
if (dados.nome[tam_nome - 1] == '\n'){
    dados.nome[tam_nome - 1] = '\0';
}
```

Deixo ainda uma última nota que a função `strupr` que está a utilizar não é standard, e que para alguns sistemas operativos não terá implementação.

[Exemplo desta solução no Ideone](https://ideone.com/XPs9jp)

<sub>Tirei o strupr no Ideone para poder funcionar</sub>

**Edit**:

Como alternativa ao `strupr` recomendo implementar manualmente mesmo, uma vez que é uma função pequena e consideravelmente simples. Nesse sentido poderia implementa-la assim por exemplo:

```
char* strupr(char *str){
    size_t str_size = strlen(str); //saber o tamanho da que entrou
    //criar espaço para a nova mais o terminador
    char *upr = malloc(sizeof(char) * (str_size + 1));
    if (!upr){ //se não deu para alocar memoria
        return NULL; //retorna NULL como indicando que algo falhou
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){ //percorrer a antiga
        upr[i] = toupper(str[i]); //converter cada letra para maiuscula
    }
    upr[i] = '\0'; //colocar o terminador no fim da convertida    
    return upr;
}
```

A conversão para maiúscula foi feita utilizando a função [`toupper`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) em cada letra.

Esta implementação mantem a semântica da função `strupr` que estava a utilizar. Eu em particular não gosto desta semântica pois é alocada memoria dentro da função com `malloc`. Isso implica que a menos que o programa termine de seguida, será necessário liberar a memoria da `string` convertida com [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/), sob pena de ter uma fuga de memória.

Comment: o que voce recomenda para substituir a função strupr?

Comment: @Tshellsi Editei a resposta com a minha sugestão